# How to avoid the edge effects that may occur when applying the Hilbert transform (by mirroring)?

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, transform, hilbert-transform

How to avoid the edge effects that may occur when applying the Hilbert transform (by mirroring) for image or image series signal?
Code is appreciated (in python) please.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid edge effects. The impulse response of a Hilbert Transformer is is infinite it both time directions. It's not just IIR is it is infinitely non-causal. Any practical implementation will be trade off between an ideal Hilbert Transform and the artifacts your specific application can tolerate.

Comment: I think mirroring will minimize the edge effects of any filtering.

Comment: @Hilmar thanks for your correction. mirroring is my purpose, then i may only need to know how to mirror the image or image series signal.